# How to disable multiple network adapters from windows command prompt with wildcard

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, wmic, netsh

I'm trying to disable multiple network adapters having a similar name in batch. Some resources I've found seem to suggest that "call disable" should work

```
wmic nic where "Name like 't%'" call disable
```

however I get `disable - Invalid alias verb.`

I can get the adapter names via:

```
wmic nic where "Name like 't%'" GET name
```

but any attempt at looping to disable them has been a fail (no real experience with cmd commands). Also took a look at netsh - not sure which is better suited for this simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I used:

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where "Name like 't%'" call disable
```

or with double percent %% to escape it if in batch file (also have to run as admin)

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where "Name like 't%%'" call disable
```